# How to display state to HTML with following JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

JSON:

[image]

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var output ="" + data.data[i].location.location.country + "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable of parsed Json is called data, so:

`var data = JSON.parse("<json-string>");`,
Then you can get the state simply like so:

`var state = data.data[0].location.location.state;`

You can then display that state variable in HTML using jquery like so: `$("div.container").html(state)`

That jquery code assumes you have included a script reference to the  jquery library and your HTML does have a  element with a class name of container, so something like `.

if you don't have jquery or just simply prefer not to use it, you can do: `document.write(state)`.

Lastly, if your JSON has a collection of data elements in it, then you can use the for loop to iterate each data element and display the state for each data element like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
var output ="" + data.data[i].location.location.state + "";
$("div.container"+i).html(output);
//document.write(output + "<br/>"); // without jquery
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Initially, we have to parse a json string by using $.parseJSON
Then, try this

```
Here response is your json string that is shown in image
var data = $.parseJSON(response);
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      var output = "" + data.data[i].location.location.country + "";
}
```